# Is chi square test appropriate for testing frequencies of modifications?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, bioinformatics

I have a lot of sequence reads from next generation sequencing that I'm converting to a sequence of *number of Stops*, sorted by position on a specific gene. Such a sequence can look like:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 123 0 0 2 1 0 16 0 0
```

I'd like to compare treated and untreated samples that may or may not differ in the amount of *number of Stops*. The paper I'm referencing to uses a chi square test for every position to filter out positions with signicantly more stops in the treated sample (compared to the untreated one) by using a 2x2 contingency table:

```
                                         Treated     Untreated
number of Stops as pos X on gene Y (k)        74            25
Total number of stops on gene Y    (z)      6047          3646
```

I assume the null hypothesis to be "the ratio of k/z is the same in treated as in untreated samples".

It this use of a chi square test appropriate? If not, what else should we look into?